# How to create onClickListener for Gallery?

Tags: android

How to register a click for a image in a gallery?

For Example. When a image is clicked a url opens up

EDIT: Errors i get when using the method below.

```
08-05 13:40:38.875: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:282)
 08-05 13:40:38.875: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.widget.Gallery.onSingleTapUp(Gallery.java:867)
 08-05 13:40:38.875: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:557)
08-05 13:40:38.875: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.widget.Gallery.onTouchEvent(Gallery.java:842)
08-05 13:40:38.875: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:4600)
08-05 13:40:38.875: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1488)
08-05 13:40:38.875: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1256)
08-05 13:40:38.875: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
08-05 13:40:38.875: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269)
08-05 13:40:38.875: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
08-05 13:40:38.875: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269)
08-05 13:40:38.875: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
08-05 13:40:38.875: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269)
08-05 13:40:38.875: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
08-05 13:40:38.875: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269)
08-05 13:40:38.875: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1700)
08-05 13:40:38.875: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1270)
08-05 13:40:38.875: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2277)
```

EDIT: Here i am retreiving the images from a text document url.

```
 public void getImages() throws IOException{


    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("https://example.com/webImages.txt");
    HttpResponse response;

    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


    HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

    BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

    InputStream is = buf.getContent();


    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is), 8);

    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    total.append(line + "\n");


     Log.v("getImage1", "Retreived image");
              imageUrl = total.toString();

          }

     }
```

Since the URL is retrieved from the TEXT doc how will i change the setTag every time the URL is changed inside the text document for the images to be retreived?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use getItemAtPosition() to get the clicked object:

You can find some more info here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

**Edited:**

Assign the URL inside getView() in your ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
int mGalleryItemBackground;
private Context mContext;

private Integer[] mImageIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2
};

private String[] mImageURLs = {
        "http://www.example1.com",
        "http://www.example2.com"
};

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
    TypedArray attr = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
    mGalleryItemBackground = attr.getResourceId(
            R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
    attr.recycle();
}

public int getCount() {
    return mImageIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

    imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);

    //Add url
    imageView.setTag(mImageURLs[position]);

    imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

    return imageView;
}
```

}

And then read that urs inside OnItemClick():

```
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {            
         String url = view.getTag().toString();
        //next use this url to open in a browser
    }
});
```

Comment: So how would i go about loading a URL depending on which view is clicked?

Comment: Maybe you could assist with the problems above.

Comment: You have to assign the url for each image object so then you can read from it and open in the browser. Could you show us your code?

Comment: Where do you get the list of images and their addresses?

Comment: The code is Extremely long because i am reading from a text document from a URL and then reading the URL from it to locate the images since they wont stay the same. How could i set the url for a particular image if the image is loaded from a URL?

Comment: You can use imageView.setTag([the URL for that image]) and then just read that tag inside onItemClick()

Comment: But since the images change..How could i change the url for the webView to load once they are clicked?

Comment: Wow Thanks alot for the Edit. Thats how i am retreiving my images. I see how yu set the tag. The only question is how will it know which URL tag belongs to which image? And how could i change the tag once the images are changed after development?

Comment: position of the images inside the mImageIds array have to be the same as positions of the urls inside the mImageURLs array. Hope this help, but it would be a lot easier to understand your problem if I could look on your code :D

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

                Log.i("Click event","In gallery"+arg2);  //arg2 provides the image position
                wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                                 wv.loadUrl(url);

   });
```

Comment: How could i go about knowing which image was clicked in the view?

Comment: The error comes from wvload(url). For some reason it doesnt want to accept it. it gives the error comlains above. but works when i comment. wv.loadUrl(url); method

Comment: please check my edited answer for finding out image position. And r u passing the correct url (Eg. www.google.com) in the place of `wv.loadUrl(url);`

Comment: do you want to open the URL inside the app (in the WebView) or in the webrowser?

Comment: I want to open it inside of the app. Depending on what view is clicked in the listener. If a certain view is clicked such as View 2 then i want a certain URL to open up in a webview. Ive already created the XML with the WebView but is in a different layout? Maybe thats what the complain in debug was about.

Comment: I may need to create new activities. And depending on which item is clicked then a certain activity opens with a certain URL for the particular image in the gallery